# Unable to download crumb string (from jenkins server ) for invoking build commands remotely

Tags: xml, curl, jenkins, automation, csrf-protection

I am trying to invoke jenkins build job through remote way and as needed trying to get crumb string from jenkins using wget/curl in following ways,

```
wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user myjenkinsuser --password mypasswd --output-document - 'http://myjenkins_ip:8082/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'

curl -s 'http://myjenkinsuser:myjenkinsuser_APIToken@myjenkins_ip:8082/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
```

Unfortunately both the command neither printing crumb string as a output nor providing any errors; it just prompt to the next terminal line.

Kindly, tell me what am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I checked "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" in jenkins.com/configureSecurity section and it started working.

[image]